How to give and display the name (in the legend) to a geom_ribbon in ggplot?
I just added a shadded area to my plot to highlight a given region of the plot using geom_ribbon. However I cannot figure out how to define a name to this ribbon and how to male it display on the legend. In the case below I actually have two ribbons I want to display on my graph.
TM_M_WILD_plot <- ggplot(data = TM_M_WILD, aes(x = Age, y = MeasurementValue, group = Sex, colour = Sex, fill= Sex)) +
  #geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  #geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, colour= 'black', linetype="twodash")+
  geom_point(size = 4.5) +
  geom_ribbon(data = TM_M_WILD, aes(ymin = 163, ymax = 386), 
              alpha= 0.6, colour = NA, fill= "royalblue")+
  geom_ribbon(data = TM_M_WILD, aes(ymin = 331, ymax = 979), 
              alpha= 0.6, colour = NA, fill= "orange")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0), limits=c(0, 40), breaks = seq(0, 40, 5))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0), limits=c(0, 1000), breaks = seq(0, 1000, 200), guide=guide_axis(minor.ticks = TRUE))+
  labs(
    x = "Age (years)",
    y = "Body Mass (Kg)",
    title = "Body mass by age")+
  theme_gray(base_size = 55
  )

TM_M_WILD_plot

TM_M_WILD_plot + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
                       #panel.border = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = 'black', size = 2),
                       #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                       panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", size=0.5),
                       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                       axis.line = element_line(size = 0.9, linetype = "solid", colour = "black"),
                       #axis.text = element_text(face="bold"),
                       axis.text = element_text(colour="black"),
                       legend.position="none",
                       legend.title = element_blank(),
                       #plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
                       plot.title = element_blank(),
                      
)


The usual way to get information into a legend is to have a property of the geom depend on a column from the data. Say, have the fill aesthetic of geom_ribbon depend the data. You can make a dedicated data frame to accomplish this if it isn't convenient in your primary data frame. Can you make an example with a simple data set and much less formatting of the plot? Include the code to make the data set and also the initial call to the ggplot() function.

The things you want to appear as legend items need to be declared inside aes(). In your case , you can move fill =, then assign your colours using scale_*_manual().
There are a few contradictions in your code e.g. assigning colour = sex but then you set scale_color_manual(values = c('black')) and defining titles but then running legend.title = element_blank(). As such, a number of modifications were made to your code. Further, it makes sense to plot your points on top of your ribbons.
This example uses a a 'toy' dataset as you did not provide one. Please review How to make a great R reproducible example to learn what is expected in a question like this.
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
set.seed(42)
TM_M_WILD <- data.frame(
  Age = sample(5:39, 100, replace = TRUE),
  MeasurementValue = runif(100, 10, 900),
  Sex = sample(c("Female", "Male"), 100, replace = TRUE)
  )

ggplot(
  data = TM_M_WILD,
  aes(Age, MeasurementValue, colour = Sex)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 163, ymax = 386, fill = "Ribbon 1"), 
              alpha = 0.6,
              colour = NA) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 331, ymax = 979, fill = "Ribbon 2"), 
              alpha = 0.6,
              colour = NA) +
  geom_point(size = 4.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "#F8766D")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Ribbons",
                    values = c("royalblue", "orange")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0),
                     limits=c(0, 40),
                     breaks = seq(0, 40, 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                     limits = c(0, 1000),
                     breaks = seq(0, 1000, 200),
                     guide = guide_axis(minor.ticks = TRUE)) +
  labs(x = "Age (years)",
       y = "Body Mass (Kg)",
       title = "Body mass by age") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 10) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", linewidth = 0.5),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.9, linetype = "solid", colour = "black"))



Thank you very much! It works, but how do I remove the legend Sex?

Yes, I had the legend "turned off" when I copied the code. The points actually refer to a single sex and how do you plot them on top of the ribbons exactly?

@JPM - replace aes(Age, MeasurementValue, colour = Sex)) + with aes(Age, MeasurementValue) +, geom_point(size = 4.5) + with geom_point(size = 4.5, colour = "black) + (or whatever colour your need), and delete scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "#F8766D")) +. And geoms are plotted in the order you declare them, so add the points last.

@JPM - same principle applies. If you don't want a legend, don't declare colour/fill/group etc. inside aes() and assign aesthetics outside aes() instead.

Thank you, I removed those elements and it worked perfectly!
